# Setting Windows Serviceat a particular time in .net

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, windows-services

Can We Set a windows Service at a particular time in a day?
Then make the Service calls after every scheduled time.
Also can I set Windows Service at a particular time on particular day in a week?

Comment: Try creating a windows scheduled task and in that task you can specify when you start and stop your service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no settings for scheduling Windows Services (which are typically expected to run 24/7), but if your needs are modest, [you can use scheduled tasks to start/stop a service at regular times](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#ScheduleStartStop). This technique is very effective when working around backups, updates, and other scheduled "downtime" events.